# jquery remove parent not working on dynamically created divs

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

im trying to use jquery in order to make a button remove its parent div.

my markup:

```
<div class="web_store_fields" id="web_store_input1">
<p>
<label for="web_store_address[]"  >Store Address : </label>        
<input name="web_store_address[]" class="web_store_info"  type="text" value="http://www." size="35"/>
<input class="button_remove_web_store" type="button" value="Remove"  />
</div>
```

jquery div removal code:

```
$('.button_remove_web_store').click(function() {
$(this).parents("div:first").remove();
});
```

this works ok for the div that's in the html when the page loads but not for 
div created dynamically by user (using this jquery code):

```
$('#button_add_web_store').click(function() {
var num = $('.web_store_fields').length;
var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      
var newElem = $('#web_store_input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'web_store_input' + newNum);
$('#web_store_input' + num).after(newElem);
});
```

just to be clear, the dynamic creation is working fine, the problem is removing those divs.

any tips would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a delegated handler ([on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) with the class as the selector so that any new buttons that get added later will still work.

```
$('body').on('click', '.button_remove_web_store', function() {
    $(this).parents("div:first").remove();
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's working!
i'm a jquery newbie and apparently there's a lot i don't know..

Comment: "live" has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9 -- it should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not** use a [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler -- it has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and **removed in jQuery 1.9** -- a breaking change for a great many people.

Instead, use the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler, which is the recommended way now:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button_remove_web_store', function() {
    $(this).parents("div:first").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently was running into an issue with [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that unclear and very similar to this application, as most "remove this's parent" functions are.

To illustrate with this question's example:

```
$('.web_store_fields').on('click', '.button_remove_web_store', function(e){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

the big catch here is the second parameter.  you must select the container `$('.container')` and pass the element selector of the 'button' as the second parameter to the `.on` function. so a definition(of sorts)

```
$('.container').on('click', '.myremovebutton', function(e){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```